# SQL How To Display Month Difference Between Return And Purchase Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I need help with writing the query that will say month difference between return and purchase dates, see the example below.

| Product | PurchaseDate (dd/mm/yy) | ReturnDate (dd/mm/yy) | Month (expected result) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car A | 01/01/2021 | 15/01/2021 | Month0 |
| Car B | 01/01/2021 | 20/02/2021 | Month1 |
| Car C | 01/01/2021 | 01/03/2021 | Month2 |

Where Month0 = the same month, Month1 = the next month and so on.

I thought about using MONTH function. Something like MONTH(ReturnDate) - MONTH(PurchaseDate), however, I found an issue when I have different years. Would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Date functions are highly database specific.

Comment: It depends on exactly what you want.  `datediff` detects the number of month boundaries crossed.  If you can accept that the result of `datediff(month,{d '2021-05-31'}, {d '2021-06-01'})` says that 1 day = 1 month, `datediff` works for you.  If not, you may need a more complex solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server then you can use `datediff()` to get the difference then concat() with string 'Month'.

```
select Product, PurchaseDate,   ReturnDate,     
concat('Month',datediff(month,PurchaseDate,ReturnDate))Month
from yourtable
```

As you mentioned in the question you can also use `Month()` function to get both months then subtract Return month from Purchase month

```
select Product, PurchaseDate,   ReturnDate,     
concat('Month',month(ReturnDate)-month(PurchaseDate))Month
from yourtable
```

For MySQL it will be `timestampdiff()`

```
select Product, PurchaseDate,   ReturnDate,     
concat('Month',timestampdiff(month,PurchaseDate,ReturnDate))Month
from yourtable
```

And for Oracle it will be `MONTHS_BETWEEN()`. In this scenario bigger date will be put first in the function then the smaller date.

```
select Product, PurchaseDate,   ReturnDate,     
concat('Month',MONTHS_BETWEEN(ReturnDate,PurchaseDate))Month
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datediff` function in MS SQL. I am assuming that this is available in your version of SQL.

In the following example, I am using date format `mm/dd/yyyy` but you can change
it to `dd/mm/yyyy` as per your example.

```sql
select 'Month' + cast(datediff(month, '01/01/2021', '01/15/2021') as varchar)

select 'Month' + cast( datediff(month, '01/01/2021', '02/20/2022') as varchar)
```

```
-- output statement 1
Month0

-- output statement 2
Month13
```

Comment: Forgot about DATEDIFF. Thanks a lot for the help!